# Writing to a file on Android issue

Tags: java, android

I am currently trying to paste current time into a file for an Android application. The code looks like this but the file is not created. I have enabled the permission of my application to write on the SD card through the manifest. Any ideas?

```
    Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
    today.setToNow();
    try {
        File myFile = new File("/sdcard/mysdfile.txt");
        myFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = 
                                new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        SimpleDateFormat dF = new SimpleDateFormat("HHMMSS");
        StringBuilder current = new StringBuilder(dF.format(today));
        myOutWriter.append(current);
        myOutWriter.close();
        fOut.close();

    }
```

Comment: try `File myFile = new File("sdcard/mysdfile.txt");` once.

Comment: Did not work. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() instead of hard-coding the `/sdcard/` path.

`File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "mysdfile.txt");`

I've tried running your code and it crashes due to `dF.format(today)`.

Instead of having this,

```
 Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
 today.setToNow();
```

It works well with this

```
Date today = new Date();
```

This code works on my device.

```
Date today = new Date();

try {
    File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "mysdfile.txt");            
    myFile.createNewFile();

    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
    OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
    SimpleDateFormat dF = new SimpleDateFormat("HHMMSS");
    StringBuilder current = new StringBuilder(dF.format(today));
    myOutWriter.append(current);
    myOutWriter.close();
    fOut.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: not 100% agree with you, i too use `sdcard/Dir-Name` in my code and it works fine.

Comment: Yes, but not all devices will have the same path name. It is safer not to hardcode the path. As it may fail on some devices.

Comment: Tried, did not bring any results. Thanks for the effort/suggestion either way.

Comment: Hi GGe, could you please try to check what does `myFile.createNewFile();` return? True or False? 
true if the file has been created, false if it already exists?

Also, how about try removing `myFile.createNewFile();` ?

Comment: It should work if your code is similar to this [File saving snippet](https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/save-file-to-sd-card)

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check

Comment: I changed the way I actually get the current date/time and it works perfectly. Thanks a lot for the help. Wish you the best.

Answer (score 0):

Try another way as follows,

```
private BufferedWriter buff = null;
private File logFile = null;
logFile = new File ( "/sdcard/mysdfile.txt" );
if ( !logFile.exists() )
{
    logFile.createNewFile();
}
buff = new BufferedWriter ( new FileWriter ( logFile,true ) );
buff.append( "Write what you want to store" );
buff.close();
```

Also you need to give `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>` permission in your AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Any error you got ? because the above code working perfectly in my case. Please update your question with the file permission you have given.

Comment: It was an issue with parsing the date and converting it to a string actually it seems. However thanks a lot for the help. Have a nice day.